# Entering USA as a Canadian PR on an ESTA with a one way flight to enter Canada through a port of entry

Tags: esta

so I’m currently an Australia citizen & Canadian permanent resident. I currently do not hold my PR for Canada and on the advise of my lawyer will be entering Canada through the United States at a port of entry. When I arrive in the US, I am visiting friends in Phoenix for 1 month before I head to the Canadian border. I am entering the US on an ESTA from Australia through the VWP on a one way ticket. Will I be okay in this case since I have proof I am permanently leaving the US to Canada since I don’t have a return flight? It’s justtt too late for me to get a B2 visa since I leave in a week. Thank you!

Comment: What documentation do you have which shows you will be going to Canada?

Comment: A "port of entry" is just a place where you enter Canada, and includes airports. Have you been advised to enter at a land border? Is that what you are doing? There is in general no need to enter at a land boarder when you first arrive as a PR.

Comment: I take "I’m currently a Canadian permanent resident. I currently do not hold my PR for Canada." to mean that you have been approved for permanent residency but have not yet "landed" to claim your PR status.

Comment: @jcaron I have my Confirmation or Permanent residency, Verification of Status and also a letter from my Canadian lawyer stating my travel plans.

Comment: Are you currently in Canada?

Comment: @djclayworth I became a PR in 2006. I moved back tok australia with my family but am now moving back to Canada. I’m just moving back permanently to renew my status. Long story. But basically since I do not currently hold my PR card, my lawyer advised me to enter through the land border.

Comment: I’m currently in Australia, leaving to head back to Canada, but stopping in the US to visit family friends before I enter through the canada through the canada US border

Comment: How are you getting from Phoenix to the Canadian border?

Comment: I have a plane ticket from Phoenix to Bellingham, then either bus or get a family friend in Washington to drive me to the border crossing.

Comment: I have enough evidence to prove to the TSA officer that I’ll be leaving america to live in Canada. I’ll even give them the option to call my lawyer to confirm. I have letters from my family in Canada saying the address I’ll be staying at. I have a letter from my friends in Phoenix stating that I’m also moving to Canada. I’m just curious if it’ll be as issue on the ESTA in my situation without a return ticket.

Comment: "I have enough evidence to prove to the TSA officer that I’ll be leaving america to live in Canada": I suspect that you may have a harder time with the airline agent checking you in for your flight.  I don't have enough experience traveling with VWP companions to know, but it seems (from anecdotes here) as though the airlines may not pay much attention to the round trip ticket requirement.  At this point, however, your only options seem to be to chance it or to cancel your flight.  I'd probably chance it.

Comment: @Kyron TSA aren't concerned with your immigration matters, you mean CBP.

Answer (score 2):

Officially one of the requirements to enter the US using the Visa Waiver Program is that you are "in possession of a round-trip transportation ticket".  [This previous answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153972/entering-the-us-with-esta-visa-waiver-program-with-a-one-way-flight-and-a-bus-ti) includes links to the specific legislation that covers this requirements and includes further details on the exact requirements.

Given your specific circumstances it's likely that US immigration would allow your entry, however your issue will not be with US immigration, but with your airline.

Enforcement of the "return ticket" requirement is carried out by the airline that carries you to the US.  They have a legal obligation to confirm that you meet certain criteria before they are allowed let you board the flight - and a return ticket is one of those conditions.

Realistically I don't believe anyone other than possibly the airline will be able to give you a definitive answer as to whether they will allow you board the flight to the US. By the letter of the law, it's a clear-cut 'no', however it's possible they will make an exception based on your Canadian PR - but officially doing so leaves them open to being fined by the US Government for allowing you board a flight without meeting the VWP requirements.

Comment: okay sweet. So in this situation, would my best bet be to book an outbound refundable flight to say a country in Europe just to cover my back, and then show that to United airlines on the day of my departure?

Comment: I think any country would do, and Canada would be much cheaper than Europe.

Comment: Booking a refundable flight out would be the safest option.  Officially the flight needs to be to somewhere outside of North America/Caribbean. ie, a flight to Canada is generally NOT good enough, however with your Canadian PR it would probably be acceptable.

Comment: Awesome. Well I just spoke to United airlines in the phone and they confirmed that if I show the evidence at the check in desk that I my final destination is Canada, I will be able to board the flight. In the worst case, I had already booked a flight to Canada before I realised you couldn’t fly to A neighbouring country on the ESTA, so be tho at could be proof that I’m atleast trying to do the right thing. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: @Kyron, Doc: a flight to Canada is explicitly acceptable under [8 CFR 217.2(c)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/217.2) if the traveler resides in Canada.  The question then is whether CBP or the airline agent checking in the passenger would accept that Kyron resides in Canada even though Kyron does not have a PR card on hand.  Other evidence is probably acceptable.

Comment: @Kyron we've done a very similar journey (NZ to Mexico) on Esta as Mexico residents (without residents ID at that stage).  Had a refundable flight to Mexico to satisfy the airline to allow us to board (although I don't recall having to even show proof that to them - different airline, booked for just short of 90 days later).  CBP didn't ask and we didn't mention the flight, just said we were moving to Mexico (driving) and we had no problems being admitted to the US.