# Is an "onward" flight always acceptable for travelling to the US under the Visa Waiver Program (ESTA)

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I plan to fly to the US under the VWP (ESTA) program, using a one-way flight from Taiwan (TPE) to Los Angeles (LAX).
I will also book a one-way flight from LAX to Chicago (ORD), and another one-way flight from Indianapolis to Italy (IND-EWR-MXP).

As far as I know, VWP requires proof of an "onward" ticket, which, in may case, would be the IND-EWR-MXP one.

However, the official ESTA regulation mentions explicitly "round trip" tickets (https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/217.2#c), although the definition of round trip ticket is quite broad (as mentioned here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/153975/124161).

Is my exit flight from the US (IND-EWR-MXP) appropriate to allow my entrance in the US in Los Angeles under the VWP?

Answer (score 8):

The relevant wording is this:

> at the time of arrival must have a round trip ticket that will transport the traveler out of the United States to any other foreign port or place as long as the trip does not terminate in contiguous territory or an adjacent island; except that the round trip ticket may transport the traveler to contiguous territory or an adjacent island, if the traveler is a resident of the country of destination.

Since you will arrive in the US in possession of a ticket that will take you to "any foreign port or place" (MXP), you are eligible for VWP.  The fact that you're not returning to where you started from is not relevant.

Comment: This is correct, but it ought to include a link to, or at least a citation identifying, the source of the "relevant wording" (which is found in 8 CFR 217.2(a)).

Comment: @phoog The OP already linked to it in their own question!

Comment: OP linked to 8 CFR 217.2 but cited 8 CFR 217.2(c).  Someone looking in (c) for the language quoted here will not find it.